# ''Stack around the variable was corrupted". How to determine size of the array?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, size

I am supposed to write a simple program that will allow the user to input their last name into the program. The program will then output their last name onto the screen. However, when I run the program I see the error "Stack around the variable last was corrupted". Luckily this is a very short program, however, I am still confused what exactly is causing the issue to occur.

I have tried changing the size of the array from the number of elements in it to the number of bytes in it. I attempted this since the array is made up of characters and not integers.

The assignment states that the entered array may not be larger than 10 (composed of 9 characters). This is why the global variable "MAX" is present.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

const int MAX = 10;

int main()
{ 
    char last[MAX];
    int size = 0;

    cout << "Enter you last name with no more than 9 characters: "
             << endl;
    cin >> last[MAX];

    size = sizeof(last);

    cout << "This is your last name: " << endl;
    cin >> last;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `last[MAX]` is off the end of the array. Valid indices for `last` run from 0 up to `MAX - 1`. But the code only reads one character; that input line really should be `std::cin >> last;`. Even better, use `std::string`; then you won't have to limit the size of the input.

Comment: `sizeof(last);` is `MAX`, regardless of the data `last` contains.

Comment: I'd suggest changing the use of C-style arrays to `std::array` and then the answer to "How to determine size of the array?" becomes "call `.size()`".

Comment: wow I just realized I used a cin statement for the output statement after "Here is your last name: "

Answer (score 4):

```
char last[MAX];
cin >> last[MAX];
```

The array has MAX element, and the index starts at 0. Which means the last element is at index MAX-1;

> Stack around the variable last was corrupted

This is because you are accessing `last[MAX]`, which is past the allocated memory for the array.

It should be

```
cin >> last;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cin >> last[MAX];
```

should be

```
cin >> last;
```

but even better use `std::string` instead of char array.

`last[MAX]` does out of bound access, (and would only allow to retrieve one char)